# Hairs aren't appearing in sculpt mode 3.6

Tags: particles, hair, sculpt-mode

I just downloaded version 3.6 of Blender thinking it'd be easier to create hair with, but every time I enter sculpt mode and drag my mouse I don't see any hairs except for one on the cheek for some reason. What am I doing wrong? I'm adding an empty hair curve first. `Does anyone know of a tutorial where this is explained?`

Comment: it's hard to say why as you did not provide a blend file, what might happen is that your normals are flipped (so the hairs could be appearing inside mesh). Another possibility is that initial mesh did not have UV map (which is needed to use hair curves)

Comment: I don't know how to upload a blender file

Comment: That seemed to fix it though, unwrapping the mesh